# Does Image.open() distort grayscale PNG images?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

Recently, I've been trying to load some grayscale images into my Python program using Pillow's `Image.open()`. However, I've been finding that the image gets distorted, and all the values polarized.

This is the image generated by the Mac preview:

[image]

And, this is the image generated by the `Image.open()` function:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mod_path2 = Path("/Volumes/Sans/ROI/Images/sub-S03046_ses-E06791_run-1_bp-chest_vp-pa_dx.png")
b = Image.open(str(mod_path2))
plt.imshow(b)
plt.show()
```

And, the characteristics of the image via preview is:

[image]

I believe that this may have something to do with either the color space of the image or the lack of the alpha channel, as an image that had both was loaded in correctly.

Comment: Please share your *"unhappy"* image - preferably via Dropbox or Google Drive so that imgur doesn't alter it. Also please show your actual, complete minimal code.

Comment: @MarkSetchell .Thanks for the response. Personally, I see very little difference between the imgur and images on my computer. I've also updated the code. Thanks!

Comment: Obviously the imgur image isn't `3050 x 2539`. Also, since you're dealing with CT data, you might have some `float` format with any values, and get some corrupted output due to clipping of `float` values to the range `[0.0 ... 1.0]`. That's why Mark specifically asked to provide the original image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell here's the link to the image: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IdmxrQpP-C0tppJC0O1Dg14u5fcMBZJg?usp=sharing.

Comment: @HansHirse Thanks, I've shared the true image. Also, if the clipping really is happening, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: why do you use matplotlib.show() instead of Image.show ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `float` values, but your CT scan is a 16-bit unsigned integer grayscale image. When opening this image using `Image.open`, the corresponding [mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#modes) is given with `I`, which is wrong here, since `I` is "32-bit signed integer pixels", whereas we'd rather like to have mode `I;16`, which is "16-bit unsigned integer pixels".

```py
b = Image.open('images/sub-S03046_ses-E06791_run-1_bp-chest_vp-pa_dx.png')
print('Pillow mode: {}'.format(b.mode))

min_val, max_val = b.getextrema()
print('Minimum value: {}, maximum value: {}'.format(min_val, max_val))
```

Output:

```
Pillow mode: I
Minimum value: 0, maximum value: 59551
```

Now, in general, [`plt.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) is able to show Pillow `Image` objects, but there seems to be an issue when showing `I` mode `Image` objects: It seems (see below image, see the lower, right corner of the plot window), that the assumed 32 bits are interpreted as RGBA values. So, even setting `vmin` and `vmax` in `plt.imshow` doesn't work here.

Strangely, when converting to mode `I;16`, the whole image is (still) clipped at `32767` – which I don't understand and can't explain. So, the corresponding plot is still faulty (see below image).

The only way to get a proper output from `plt.imshow` seems to be to convert the image to some NumPy array, explicitly setting the `dtype` to `np.uint16`, and then convert back to a Pillow `Image` object with mode `I;16`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

b = Image.open('images/sub-S03046_ses-E06791_run-1_bp-chest_vp-pa_dx.png')
print('Pillow mode: {}'.format(b.mode))

min_val, max_val = b.getextrema()
print('Minimum value: {}, maximum value: {}'.format(min_val, max_val))

plt.figure(0, figsize=(18, 5))
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1), plt.imshow(b, vmin=min_val, vmax=max_val, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Pillow image, original mode I'), plt.colorbar()

plt.subplot(1, 3, 2), plt.imshow(b.convert('I;16'), vmin=min_val, vmax=max_val, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Pillow image, converted to mode I;16'), plt.colorbar()

b = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(b).astype(np.uint16), 'I;16')
plt.subplot(1, 3, 3), plt.imshow(b, vmin=min_val, vmax=max_val, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Pillow image after NumPy array conversion'), plt.colorbar()

plt.tight_layout(), plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
Matplotlib:    3.3.4
NumPy:         1.20.1
Pillow:        8.1.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: would the issue for the I;16 cap be that the max value of an integer with that many bits is 32767? If that is the case, is there a mode maybe like I;32(32 bit unsigned integer pixels) that would work better?